# It can be unlikely to see

Tags: meaning-in-context

In AE, that would usually mean "I would like to order the same thing that she has just ordered." In these days of COVID-19 diner separation, but to some extent also in earlier times with more crowding, it ***can*** be unlikely to see someone at another table who happens to be eating exactly what you want.

Source: https://forum.wordreference.com/conversations/i-have-a-question-about-your-reply.1629437/#convMessage-1935882

---

I'd like to know what exactly the bold word means in that context.
Thank you very much.

Comment: _It can be..._ = _it often happens that it is..._

Comment: The word **unlikely** is used incorrectly. *You may be unlikely to see anyone...* would be more idiomatic than *It can be unlikely to see anyone...*.